# Is running ldconfig inside fakeroot possible?

Tags: linux, chroot

I am trying to run debian wheezy in chroot (got debian files from https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/02108ee636f54b504e2aec4ee7bb59a2de8a5b99/wheezy/rootfs.tar.xz)

That is the way i'm using it:

```
user$>fakechroot fakeroot-ng chroot /home/user/wheezy
```

When installing packages with apt-get, ldconfig is executed, but it fails with an error:

```
ldconfig: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

- selinux on host os is not installed
- /home/user/wheezy/sbin/ldconfig permissions are -rwxr-xr-x

Is it possible to find a workaround for that without running under root?

I wonder if, in general, it is possible to get things work in such environment, e.g. install packages, run servers (ports above 1024, of course), scripts etc?

Answer (score 0):

/home/user/wheezy/etc is probably not writable for you.

As a side note, you may like to take a look at the [Schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) package if you actually want to run services from inside the chroot.

Comment: `echo hello > /etc/ld.so.cache~` works. Is it possible for /etc/ld.so.cache~ not to be writable for ldconfig?

Comment: ldconfig is called as `root`. Has the user `root` is mapped to on the base system rights to write to the file ? Or simply: within the chroot: can `root` touch the file?

Comment: to marcolz: root (the same user as running ldconfig) successfullly runs touch on file /etc/ld.so.cache~: `root@debian:/# touch /etc/ld.so.cache~
root@debian:/# ldconfig
ldconfig: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied`. Is it possible that ldconfig explicitly checks user it runs under?: `root@debian:/# who am i
user     pts/0        2015-07-21 07:21 (10.144.31.34)`

Comment: I wonder how fakechroot could ever function well in the first place as it uses LD_PRELOAD, which is not going to work for statically linked binaries like ldconfig... You may want to ask the developer.
In short this means that because ldconfig's open() calls are not intercepted, it is actually trying to write to the host system's /etc/ directory, instead ot the /etc inside the chroot.